# PHP: Не работает скрипт авторизации

Tags: php, sqlite3

Не работает скрипт. Точнее не происходит авторизация. Вот скрипт в файле login.php:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

  $database = glob('*.db');
  define('DB_NAME', $database[0]);
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $mdPassword = md5($password);

  $db = new SQLite3(DB_NAME);
  $result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$mdPassword' LIMIT 1");

  while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    if($row['id'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        print_r($row['id']);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Логин или пароль неверны!';
        print_r($row['id']);
    }
  }
}
```

А вот это в файле admin.php:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
else {
// Открывающийся после авторизации контент
}
```

Вывод var_dump($row['id']) при вводе верного пароля — int(1), при вводе рандомного — ничего не выводится. В обоих случаях перехода к admin.php не происходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В условие if($row['id']) добавьте header('Location: admin.php')

Comment: Да, так работает, но почему-то, при неверном пароле не выводится сообщение «Логин или пароль неверны!», т. е. не выполняется else.

Comment: Измените условие на if(isset($row['id']) && $row['id'] == 1)

Comment: К сожалению, не работает :( Просто обновляется страница и всё.

Comment: А ну понятно. Условие while не выполняется если юзер не найден. Уберите while оставьте просто $row=$result->fetchArray...

Comment: Спасибо большущее! ;)